# How can i write a more complex regexp in java?

Tags: java, regex

id like to do the following rules:

Not begining with space " ", not more than one "." , not begining with "." not end with "." not ? / \ : ; in the file.

```
public static void Invalid(String[] filename){  
for(String s: filename){     
    String u  = s;
    try {
        u = new String(s.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(u);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    u=u.replaceAll("[.$]", " ");//.{2,}\\?
    u = u.replaceAll("\\s+", "_");
    System.out.println(s + " = " + u);
}
}
```

in main just simple:

```
  String[] name={"some?thing..txt."};
  Invalid(name);
```

output:

```
 some?thing..txt.
 some?thing..txt. = some_thing_txt_
```

how can i do that?

Comment: Are you looking just to validate a filename, or actually change a filename to conform to your rules?

Comment: change it to _ for example

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern to validate the filename:

```
^[^?/\\\\;: .][^?/\\\\;:.]*(?:\\.[^?/\\\\;:.]+)?$
```

Note: if you want to allow the empty string, add `|^$` at the end.

Not sure what you exactly want to do with invalid filenames.

Comment: I just want to change the invalid to valid so now replace with _ character